# Scrape all pages for a particular item in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping stock data from Yahoo! Finance. My question is, using `LinkExtractor`, how can I combine all the pricing data for a given stock if there are multiple pages of data for each stock.

```
class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "dnot"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com", "http://eoddata.com/"]
    start_urls = ['https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=CAT&a=04&b=24&c=2005&d=04&e=24&f=2015&g=d']
    rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//td[@align="right"]/a[@rel="next"]'),
     callback='stocks1',
     follow=True),
]
```

This `start_url` will have many pages of data, so I use the rule to follow each page. `def stocks1` will then gather the data from a given page.

```
    def stocks1(self, response):

    returns_pages = []
    rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]//table/tr')[1:]
    current_page = response.url
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        try:
            values = cells[-1]
            try:
                float(values)
                returns_pages.append(values)
            except ValueError:
                continue
        except ValueError:
            continue  

     yield Request(current_page, self.finalize_stock, meta={'returns_pages': returns_pages})
```

The data for each item is stored through another function:

```
def finalize_stock(self, response):

    returns_pages =  response.meta.get('returns_pages')
    item = Website()
    items = []
    item['returns'] = returns_pages
    item['avg_returns'] = numpy.average(returns_pages)
    items.append(item)
    yield item
```

My question is how can I compile the returns from multiple pages for a single item, so that I can store it through `finalize_stock`?

Answer (score 0):

As Scrapy stores the items in memory you could do the same with an ItemPipeline element: every item processed goes through your pipeline class and you can store those items in the memory (in a list, a dictionary or as you wish).

And when you are done you can export those items into a CSV / JSON file or to a database.

For some examples look at the Scrapy documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html